# How to Prevent Jenkins Gerrit Plugin from Triggering on Trivial Changes?

Tags: jenkins, gerrit

I know that one can let gerrit preserve review scores by using the copyAllScoresOnTrivialRebase and copyAllScoresIfNoCodeChange label properties, as described in:

https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-labels.html

Now I would like to avoid triggering Jenkins validation builds in those same cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your Jenkins job cherry-pick or merge uploaded changes onto the tip of the destination branch when it builds and tests uploaded commits? If not, even a trivial rebase is interesting to build and test as it's a closer approximation of what the code eventually will look like after it's merged.

Anyway, support for filtering patch sets on the change kind was added in [Gerrit Trigger Plugin 2.12.0](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger#GerritTrigger-Version2.12.0%28releasedNov142014%29) (originally introduced in beta 3 of that release). I can't find any documentation of this feature but see [PR #159 for github.com/jenkinsci/gerrit-trigger-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gerrit-trigger-plugin/pull/159).